# jax-rs messagebodywriter with collection

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have defined the following jax-rs MessageBodyWriter:

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Customer>
....
}
```

Additionally, my rest-endpoint looks like this:

```
@Path("/api/customers)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{customerNumber})
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("customerNumber") String customerNumber) {}

    @GET
    public List<Customer> getCustomers(){}

}
```

I would like that the **CustomerMessageWriter** be used for both the `Customer and List<Customer>` response options, but i cant find away to configure this.

If it helps, I am using resteasy as the jaxrs implementation.

Note:

My Current solution is to check for the List generic type. using a totally different MessageBodyWriter, as it seems i cannot use the same MessageBodyWriter, unless i kiss generics goodbye:

```
public boolean isWriteable(@Nonnull final Class<?> type,
                           @Nonnull final Type genericType,
                           @Nonnull final Annotation[] annotations,
                           @Nonnull final MediaType mediaType) {
    if (!List.class.isAssignableFrom(type) || !MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.isCompatible(mediaType)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
        return false;
    }

    final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
    final Type actualType = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return actualType == Customer.class;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own writer for JSON. Simply use one of ones already out there, like the one from Jackson. If you are in an EE container (e.g. JBoss/Wildfly), there should already be a writer to handle JSON. If you are not in a an EE container, and you are using RESTeasy, then just add [this dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider) (pick your version)

Comment: Additionally, you may want to take a look at [Adam Bien's post about this](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_returning_a_list).

Comment: @peeskillet yes, i am aware of that. I need some special handling, where i serialize a particular object into its uuid, and deserialize it back by doing injection into the messagebodyreader and then looking up that particular object.

Comment: @maress Did you find a solution for this? I've the same problem where I need to define a custom MessageBodyWriter for a specific type but want RestEasy to handle collections of the type.

Comment: @whitlaaa Adam's solution returns a Response object.

Comment: @IceMan i simply ignored generics, create a single messagebodywriter and passed the serialization to jackson. So the message bodywriter can handle all types, even collection

Comment: @maress Not sure I understand; how did you pass on the serialization to Jackson?

Comment: @maress Did you do this by defining a Custom serializer that you registered with Jackson? This would be one way to do this.

Comment: Jackson automatically takes care of serialization of collections, unlike the jaxrs writer/reader implementations. So i simply defined a writer which accepts all class types, and application/json mediatype.

Comment: @maress It would be great it you'd provide an answer for others, because it seems like you have solved your own problem. For example, you could provide the writer you defined.